# What is wrong with this angularjs code?

Tags: angularjs

```
 @{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleapp">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <title>Directives</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        .bold {
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        .red {
            color:red;
        }
        .green {
        color:blue;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("exampleapp", []).directive("unorderedList", function (){
            return {
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) 
                {
                    scope.data=scope[attrs["unorderedList"]];
                },
                restrict: "M",
                template:"<ul><li ng-repeat='item in data'>{{item.price | currency}}</li></ul>"
            }
        }).controller("defaultctrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.products = [{ name: "Apples", category: "Fruit", price: 1.20, expiry: 10 },{ name: "Bananas", category: "Fruit", price: 2.42, expiry: 7 },{ name: "Pears", category: "Fruit", price: 2.02, expiry: 6 } ];
            $scope.incrementprices = function () {
                for(var i=0;i<$scope.products.length;i++)
                {
                    $scope.products[i].price++;
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="defaultctrl"  >
    <h3>Fruit</h3>
    <!-- directive:unordered-list products -->
</body>
</html>
```

I want apply the directive as a comment . But it did not work. So my question is how to apply angularjs directive as a  comment while using template and link directive definitions while using restrict definition.

Comment: M restrict definition option is to use the directive as a comment.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/WIEeWwb.png